# How to draw sin wave or simple 2DGraph in Qt cpp using QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Can any one help me in drawing simple 2D sin wave plot in Qt using QGraphicsView?
after some googling i found some info here [Using Qt To Draw the Graph of Sin(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921520/using-qt-to-draw-the-graph-of-sinx). but i am restricted to use only QGraphicsView without Qpainter.Thanks

Comment: Why not using mature plotting tools like QCustomPLot?

Comment: yeah you are right but my task is to restricted to QGraphicsview

Comment: You should really add more information on why you are restricted to only using QGraphicsView. You can use OpenGL for drawing. You could plot points using other QGraphicsItems. It's unclear what you really need and why. Aside from explaining the requirements better, the rest is basic trigonometry.

Comment: "only QGraphicsView without Qpainter" : Why can't you use QPainter? QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItems and QWidgets all use QPainter to render. What do you mean you can't use QPainter?